# jQuery slider as a timeline

Tags: jquery, slider, timeline

I have just finished incorporating a jQuery accordian with a jQuery Slider.
I.e.

3 pictures are displayed. The user can either use `PREV` or `NEXT` buttons to view the next/prev 3 images. They can also navigate through all the images with the slider.

The next step is to make this slider look like a timeline. The left hand side needs to start at 1970 and finish at 2010. For each item (an item is a set of 3 images in this case) I need it to show a date on the timeline.

i.e: [image]

I know I could create an image with the dates the right width apart but idealy this needs to be dynamic so more items can be put in and the timeline self updates.

Comment: What have you tried so far? What do you think might work? ------ If the user is using a `PREV` and `NEXT` buttons, is the slider going to be an extra option, or do you want to replace the buttons with one slider?

Comment: might be an idea to answer / close your question if your problem is solved, to save wasting peoples time trying to answer it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At a high level, the following should work:

1. Get the total width of the slider UI element, in pixels.
2. Divide this number by `[total number of labels] - 1` to get the total number of pixels to allocate to each label.
3. Add a series of div's immediately after the slider div with the width you got in step 2 and the `float:left` style.
4. Follow everything with an empty div with the `clear: both` style.

Here is a basic example:

**CSS**

```
.timeline {
    width: 500px;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
.timelineEntry {
    float: left;
}
.first {
    position: relative; left: 5px;
}
.last {
    position: relative; left: -10px;
}
.clear {
    clear: both;
}
```

**Markup**

```
<div id="timelineContainer">
    <div class="timeline" id="slider">
        Slider UI Goes Here
    </div>
</div>
<div class="clear"></div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
var container = document.getElementById("timelineContainer");
var labels = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10"];
var totalWidth = $("#slider").width();
var labelWidth = Math.floor(totalWidth / (labels.length - 1));
for (var index = 0; index < labels.length; index++) {
    var nextLabel = document.createElement("div");
    nextLabel.className = "timelineEntry";
    if (index == 0) {
        nextLabel.className += " first";
    }
    else if (index == labels.length - 1) {
        nextLabel.className += " last";
    }
    nextLabel.style.width = labelWidth + "px";
    nextLabel.innerHTML = labels[index];
    container.appendChild(nextLabel);
}
```