# Jquery Timeline plugins

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, timeline

I am in search for jquery timeline plugin with years on the horizontal axis.

I have seen one in the past. I am not able to find it. Did search for jquery timeline plugins.

Comment: Are you sure it wasn't just a jqueryUI scroller?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3657837/jquery-slider-as-a-timeline

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here are 2 that I had stored in my bookmarks.  They aren't jquery plugins, but they could be adapted to be jquery plugins.  [Eric Meyer's structured timeline](http://meyerweb.com/eric/thoughts/2008/01/21/structured-timeline/) and [timeplot](http://www.simile-widgets.org/timeplot/?).  I also found this service called [Tiki-Toki](http://tiki-toki.com/) which offers timelines as a web service.

Or you could just use something like [HighCharts](http://highcharts.com/) if that will work for your situation.

Answer (score 8):

Have a look at this http://timeline.verite.co/. Its real good. Plus you could have JSON or Google Spreadsheets as data sources.

Answer (score 6):

There’s [jQuery Timelinr](http://www.csslab.cl/2011/08/18/jquery-timelinr/), if you need only years.

For more data, esp. scientific use, have a look at [Timeglider](http://timeglider.com/jquery/) or [SIMILE Timeline](http://www.simile-widgets.org/timeline/) (without jQuery).

Comment: SIMILE Timeline is good, And Thanks and Honor to the author and BSD!

Answer (score 2):

[TimeGlider](http://timeglider.com/jquery/) may be useful, and free for non-commercial use.

Answer (score 2):

Two more:

[Advanced Event Timeline With PHP, CSS & jQuery](http://tutorialzine.com/2010/01/advanced-event-timeline-with-php-css-jquery/) at Tutorialzine

[Dipity](http://www.dipity.com/), to create your timeline online

Answer (score 2):

I developed a simple jQuery plugin for this purpose, although it displays the years (or century or decade--anything of your choosing) on the vertical axis. See http://www.technotarek.com/timeliner/ and http://www.technotarek.com/timeliner/timeliner.html

Answer (score 2):

A great timeline control that I have been using recently is the [CHAP Almende Timeline](http://almende.github.com/chap-links-library/timeline.html). It is simple on the surface and to use, but offers plenty of customisability. Seems fairly lightweight, and is able to handle large amounts of events on most browsers (for some reason some browsers choke a bit on large data sets when you zoom out too far). This works quite nicely on tablet touch screens too, if that is useful to you.

CHAP Almende timeline is also regularly updated by Jos de Jong at https://github.com/almende/chap-links-library  and he is pretty quick to address any issues.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone that will end up on this post, like me, on its search to jquery timeline plugins, (although it is an old question):

http://timeline.verite.co/

http://timeglider.com/jquery/

http://www.csslab.cl/ejemplos/timelinr/latest/horizontal.html

Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

I made this one, but this is just for navigation, I'm not sure what's the use case of the timeline you're looking for:

[jQuery-Timeline Plugin](https://github.com/nicolasembleton/jQuery-Timeline-Plugin)

Answer (score 1):

http://timeline.verite.co/ is good time Line JS

Answer (score 1):

You can try this enhanced jquery timelinr, it integrated jquery timelinr, cufon and animate.css. Good for simple timeline show.

Answer (score 0):

Check this out for various Timeline JavaScript libraries: http://functionn.blogspot.com/search/label/timelines#.ULj4aU_Mjs4

Alternatively, I would recommend you using:

http://functionn.blogspot.com/2012/03/timeline-javascript-library-for.html