# Looking for a good event timeline jQuery plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I am looking for a jQuery plugin that will visualize some objects(events) according to their dates an example of what I am looking for is:

[image]
I have tried **time glider** and I am looking for other options.

Thanks alot

Comment: have u considered jquery fullcalender?

Comment: I believe so Muhammad, I am looking for a non-calendar representation, Maybe a 1 axis graph representation is what I mean.

Comment: I know about this : http://www.simile-widgets.org/timeline/ But it's not jquery I think ..

Comment: Isn't this question a replicate of : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5377521/jquery-timeline-plugins

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think jQuery Timelinr would be a good choice here... Do check it out & let me know if it works well for you.

[jQuery Timelinr](http://www.csslab.cl/2011/08/18/jquery-timelinr/) is a simple plugin helps you to give more life to the boring timelines. It supports horizontal and vertical layouts, and you can specify parameters for most attributes: speed, transparency, auto-play and etc… You can also customize the style with CSS easily.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried [Simile Timeline](http://www.simile-widgets.org/timeline/)?

Comment: Cool but its not jQuery. Thanks for sharing tho.

Answer (score 0):

You can try these two demos:

Horizontal: http://www.gbin1.com/technology/democenter/20120813-css-animation-timeline/index.html

vertical: http://www.gbin1.com/technology/democenter/20120813-css-animation-timeline/index2.html

Base on timelinr and animate.css and cufon.